# Replacing multiple (only inner) spaces with a single one in PHP?

Tags: php, regex, preg-replace, pcre

```php
$test1 = ' surrounding1 ';               // No replace 
$test2 = '  surrounding2    ';           // No replace
$test3 = '  extra    spaces  between  '; // Becomes '  extra spaces between  '
```

Regular expression `'/[ ]{2,}/'` won't do the trick because matches also leading and trailing spaces. While `(?!\S+)\s{2,}(?!\S+)` [won't match all inner spaces](http://rubular.com/r/LtEv2MJr3x).

Comment: I've edited your third example to make it conform to what you've written in your question. I hope you agree with this edit.

Comment: @TimPietzcker that's right, thank you. I'll study your answer and acept it ASAP.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
$result = preg_replace(
    '/(?<!   # Assert that it is impossible to match...
     ^       #  start-of-string
    |        #  or
     [ ]     #  a space
    )        # ...before the current position.
    [ ]{2,}  # Match at least 2 spaces.
    (?!      # Assert that it is impossible to match...
     [ ]     #  a space
    |        #  or
     $       #  end-of-string
    )        # ...after the current position./x', 
    ' ', $subject);
```

Comment: @Gremo: I transformed it into a verbose regex, hope that's clearer now.

Comment: @YogeshSuthar: Yes, and it shouldn't. Gremo only wants to condense inner spaces.

Answer (score -1):

```
$test3 = preg_replace('/\s\s+/', ' ', $test3 );
```

Comment: This matches leading and trailing spaces.

Comment: no you mean trim() but this strips excess whitespace from a string.